# Generate Linkhandler for tx_news and tx_glossary2, but the last linkhandler don''t run

Tags: typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

i am trying to create a link handler for the EXT:glossary2. I have oriented myself on the link handler of tx_news, which also works fine.

When I call the linkhandler for glossary in the backend I get the following error message:

Argument 2 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\Browser\RecordBrowser::displayRecordsForPage() must be of the type string, null given, called in .../typo3/sysext/recordlist/Classes/LinkHandler/RecordLinkHandler.php on line 148

Anybody got an idea how I can make this thing work?

Here is my current code for the link handler (TSConfig):

```
TCEMAIN.linkHandler {
   tx_news {
      handler = TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\LinkHandler\RecordLinkHandler
   # A translatable label can be used with LLL:EXT:theme/locallang.xml:label
      label = News
      configuration {
         table = tx_news_domain_model_news
         # Default storage pid
         storagePid = 19
         # Hide the page tree by setting it to 1
         hidePageTree = 0
      }
      scanAfter = page
   }
   tx_glossary2 {
      handler = TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\LinkHandler\RecordLinkHandler
      label = Glossary
      configuration {
         storagePid = 2334
         hidePageTree = 0
      }
      scanAfter = page
   }
}
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TCEMAIN.linkHandler {
    tx_glossary2 {
        handler = TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\LinkHandler\RecordLinkHandler
        label = Glossary
        configuration {
            table = tx_glossary2_domain_model_glossary
            storagePid = 2334
            hidePageTree = 0
        }
        scanAfter = page
    }
}
```

The entry for the corresponding table was missing in the above example for tx_glossary2.